# AWK string conditional not working

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sh

I am trying to run through a directory and ensure that root it not the owner of any of the files. With awk, I am having an issue where comparing a field to a string does not yield an accurate result.

```
ls -d -l /path/to/file/**/* | awk '{ if ( "$3" == "root" ); print "File has wrong permissions: " $9;}'
```

What is generated is a list of files, and when double checked, whose owner and groups are not root.

> -rw-rw-r-- 1 foobar foobar 78828 Dec  4 11:15 /p/t/f/xyz/abc.jpg

Ideally, the end result would be something like:

```
ls -d -l /path/to/file/**/* | awk '{ if ("$3" != "deploy" || "$4" != "deploy") [...]
```

What is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: awk is not like shell: replace `"$3" != "deploy" ` with `$3 != "deploy" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your statement is the `;` after the if-condition. This means the if-block is empty.
Remove the `;` or better put the if-block in `{...}` and everything will work as you expect it. Moreover, you should not put fields in `"..."` (`"$3"` -> `$3`)

```
ls -d -l / | awk '{ if ( $3 == "root" ) print "File has wrong permissions: "$9;}'
```

or

```
ls -d -l / | awk '{ if ( $3 == "root" ){print "File has wrong permissions: " $9}}'
```

Comment: I knew had to be something small. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to put `$3` in quotes.  If you do it becomes a string.  In addition, you don't want a semicolon after the `if` condition - if you have it, then the `if` does nothing.  It's likely you want to make those two changes:

```
ls -d -l /path/to/file/**/* | awk '{ if ( $3 == "root" ) print "File has wrong permissions: " $9;}'
```